# How do I use a .jpg or .png as a background picture?

Tags: python, arcade

I found a nice image of space that I'd like sitting in the background of this tiny game I'm working on and can't figure out what and where to write it. It needs to be placed behind all classes to make sure that it doesn't block the screen. I thought it might be in class Window, but I'm not sure. I am brand new to python so any help is much appreciated! This is the entire project so far.

```
import sys, logging, os, random, math, open_color, arcade

#check to make sure we are running the right version of Python
version = (3,7)
assert sys.version_info >= version, "This script requires at least Python {0}.{1}".format(version[0],version[1])

#turn on logging, in case we have to leave ourselves debugging messages
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
MARGIN = 30
SCREEN_TITLE = "Intergalactic slam"
NUM_ENEMIES = 5
STARTING_LOCATION = (400,100)
BULLET_DAMAGE = 10
ENEMY_HP = 10
HIT_SCORE = 10
KILL_SCORE = 100
PLAYER_HP = 100

class Bullet(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position, velocity, damage):
        ''' 
        initializes the bullet
        Parameters: position: (x,y) tuple
            velocity: (dx, dy) tuple
            damage: int (or float)
        '''
        super().__init__("PNG/laserPink3.png", 0.5)
        (self.center_x, self.center_y) = position
        (self.dx, self.dy) = velocity
        self.damage = damage

    def update(self):
        '''
        Moves the bullet
        '''
        self.center_x += self.dx
        self.center_y += self.dy

class Enemy_Bullet(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position, velocity, damage):
        super().__init__("PNG/laserGreen1.png", 0.5)
        (self.center_x, self.center_y) = position
        (self.dx, self.dy) = velocity
        self.damage = damage
    def update(self):
        self.center_x += self.dx
        self.center_y += self.dy

class Player(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("PNG/shipYellow_manned.png", 0.5)
        (self.center_x, self.center_y) = STARTING_LOCATION
        self.hp = PLAYER_HP

class Enemy(arcade.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, position):
        '''
        initializes an alien enemy
        Parameter: position: (x,y) tuple
        '''
        super().__init__("PNG/shipGreen_manned.png", 0.5)
        self.hp = ENEMY_HP
        (self.center_x, self.center_y) = position





class Window(arcade.Window):

    def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        self.set_mouse_visible(True)
        arcade.set_background_color(open_color.black)
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.enemy_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.enemy_bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.player = Player()
        self.score = 0
        self.win = False
        self.lose = False


    def setup(self):
        '''
        Set up enemies
        '''
        for i in range(NUM_ENEMIES):
            x = 120 * (i+1) + 40
            y = 500
            enemy = Enemy((x,y))
            self.enemy_list.append(enemy)            

    def update(self, delta_time):
        self.bullet_list.update()
        self.enemy_bullet_list.update()
        if (not (self.win or self.lose)): 
            for e in self.enemy_list:
                for b in self.bullet_list:
                    if (abs(b.center_x - e.center_x) <= e.width / 2 and abs(b.center_y - e.center_y) <= e.height / 2):
                        self.score += HIT_SCORE
                        e.hp -= b.damage
                        b.kill()
                        if (e.hp <= 0):
                            e.kill()
                            self.score += KILL_SCORE
                            if (len(self.enemy_list) == 0):
                                self.win = True
                if (random.randint(1, 75) == 1):
                    self.enemy_bullet_list.append(Enemy_Bullet((e.center_x, e.center_y - 15), (0, -10), BULLET_DAMAGE))
                for b in self.enemy_bullet_list:
                    if (abs(b.center_x - self.player.center_x) <= self.player.width / 2 and abs(b.center_y - self.player.center_y) <= self.player.height / 2):
                        self.player.hp -= b.damage
                        b.kill()
                        if (self.player.hp <= 0):
                            self.lose = True                




    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text(str(self.score), 20, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 40, open_color.white, 16)
        arcade.draw_text("HP: {}".format(self.player.hp), 20, 40, open_color.white, 16)

        if (self.player.hp > 0):
            self.player.draw()

        self.bullet_list.draw()
        self.enemy_bullet_list.draw()
        self.enemy_list.draw()
        if (self.lose):
            self.draw_game_loss()
        elif (self.win):
            self.draw_game_won()

    def draw_game_loss(self):
        arcade.draw_text(str("LOSER!"), SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 90, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 10, open_color.white, 30)

    def draw_game_won(self):
        arcade.draw_text(str("WINNER!"), SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - 90, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 - 10, open_color.white, 30)

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        '''
        The player moves left and right with the mouse
        '''
        self.player.center_x = x

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        if button == arcade.MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT:
            x = self.player.center_x
            y = self.player.center_y + 15
            bullet = Bullet((x,y),(0,10),BULLET_DAMAGE)
            self.bullet_list.append(bullet)


def main():
    window = Window(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)
    window.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to add it to class window...

You could do something like this to add it:

```
 def __init__(self, width, height, title):
        super().__init__(width, height, title)
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        os.chdir(file_path)

        self.set_mouse_visible(True)
        arcade.set_background_color(open_color.black)
        self.bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.enemy_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.enemy_bullet_list = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.player = Player()
        self.score = 0
        self.win = False
        self.lose = False

        self.background = None


    def setup(self):
        '''
        Set up enemies
        '''

        self.background = arcade.load_texture("images/background.jpg")

        for i in range(NUM_ENEMIES):
            x = 120 * (i+1) + 40
            y = 500
            enemy = Enemy((x,y))
            self.enemy_list.append(enemy)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to load the `.jpg` or `.png` as a *texture*, and draw that texture each frame, as big as the screen is (or bigger!).

I haven't tested this, but as an example, loading the texture could be done in `Window.__init__`, like so ([reference](http://arcade.academy/arcade.html#arcade.load_texture)):

```
self.background = arcade.load_texture('PNG/background.png')
```

And then in `on_draw`, just after you call `start_render`, you would draw it ([reference](http://arcade.academy/arcade.html#arcade.Texture.draw)), passing the required center coordinates, as well as width and height:

```
self.background.draw(SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
```

The reason it needs to be the first thing is because everything is drawn back-to-front, like you would do in a painting.

If the image is not the exact same size as your screen/window, your background will probably be stretched/squished. If that's not what you want, the easiest fix would be to change the image so that it's the right size.

Comment: Hey thanks that worked perfectly! And thank you for the link to arcade academy, what a huge help!